# cmd.Run() Returning 'file does not exist' Error

Tags: go

I'm new to Golang, but one of its apparent strengths is in creating command-line tools so I thought a fun little learning exercise would be to recreate the *'touch'* command on Windows. I wrote a program to create a new file at either a specified filepath, or in the current folder. This has gone absolutely grand, and I can make a new file no problem:

```
func create_empty_file(file_name string) bool {
    filehandle, err := os.Create(file_name)

    if err != nil {
        return false
    }

    defer filehandle.Close()

    return true
}
```

I know that this part is working because I can watch the file being made and open it after the program is complete. My problem here is that I would like to open this file in VSCode after it is created, and there is clearly something that I don't understand about `os/exec`. When I try to run this:

```
command_string := strings.Join([]string{"code", full_filepath}, " ")
run_command := exec.Command(command_string)
run_err := run_command.Run()
```

And I print out the contents of `run_err` (obviously checking for `nil` beforehand), I get this:

`.Run() failed with error: exec: "code C:\\Go Code\\failed_successfully.go": file does not exist`

If I copy and paste `"code C:\\Go Code\\failed_successfully.go"` into my command prompt, it opens the `.go` file in VSCode without issue, so clearly there is something about this call than I'm missing/don't understand.

I thought maybe it was trying to open the file *before* it had been created, so I looked up how to check if a file exists yet and then wrote a short function using `Tick`s which checks every few milliseconds if the file exists yet and returns `true` when it finds it. Otherwise, it runs for some specified number of seconds and then returns false. I still get the same error, so I am assuming that this is not the issue.

The last thing I did was to use `strings.Replace()` to replace all of the back-slashes with forward-slashes, which has no effect.

Any advice on how to achieve what I want here would be much appreciated!

Comment: i think its the `code` executable that is not found. Your shell probably has it setup in PATH, but the shell that is brought up by golang does not.Try with the full path of `code` executable. You could also try jst `ls` to see if the file is accessible from the shell that your golang code is bringing up.

Comment: Thanks for the response - I tried hard-coding in the full path for `code` and am still getting the same error. `code` is on my PATH anyway, and as I said I can call it without issue from the command line so I wouldn't have thought this was the problem.

Comment: `exec.Command` uses `exec.LookPath` to search the system path for the executable, so hard-coding the path is not necessary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`exec.Command` does not parse the input string, splitting it on spaces and so on. Instead, pass the arguments individually to `exec.Command`.

That is:

```
runCmd := exec.Command("code", full_filepath)
```

Currently, you're trying to find a command called `code C:\\Go Code\\failed_successfully.go` -- rather than one simply called `code` and calling it with an argument.

Comment: Ah, amazing that worked!
That makes sense - thank you for your help.